# Method signature doesn't match a textbox eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

When I was use `Char.IsNumber` it creates an error in `form1.designer.cs`.

> No overload for "`textBox1_TextChanged`" matches delegate '`System.EventHandler`'

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Char value");
    }
}


///////////// Text Box ///////////////
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(73, 57);
this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 20);
this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0; 
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);  // error occurs on this line
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Change `KeyPressEventArgs` to `TextChangedEventArgs` (for WPF, for winforms use `EventArgs`).  The error is telling you that the signature for the `TextChanged` event does not match the method you are assigning to it.

Comment: I think `TextChangedEventArgs` is only in WPF, this looks like Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler doesn't match the signature for the TextChanged event, try this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
```

Also, when you do, you'll find that there is no `e.KeyChar` on the TextChanged event. Are you sure it's the event you want?

Comment: Mine is identical. The reason for using "KeyPressEventArgs " is to get KeyDown.